# Export Yahoo Messanger block list?

Tags: export, yahoo-messenger

Is there anyway to export the blocked users list in yahoo messenger ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you install the open source [Pidgin](http://www.pidgin.im/) IM program and set it up to use your Yahoo account I think it writes the blocked users at the bottom of the .purple/blist.xml file in your (Roaming) AppData folder of your profile.

You can then just copy the blocked users out of that file.

Comment: This is excellent. I am not aware of this , even I'm a regular user of Pidgin.

Answer (score 0):

***Its not possible*** .

I guess that you cant do export the block list from yahoo messenger. But you can do export or import from yahoo address and it has feature like avoid duplicate only and all contact export only

Comment: Can I get the same list from email address book ?

Comment: No .. but you cant do the block listed one

Comment: Stolen here: http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20061209194117AAeUVOv

Comment: exact copy of the content :)